# Перевод времени в unix-формат

Tags: php

Как перевести подобную строку "Sun, 21 Sep 2014 16:24:57 +0400" в unix-формат в PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, Вам нужна функция [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)